# Linux string functions

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How is this so complex or am I missing something. I simply want to get the integer value of a substring within an existing string and place it in a variable - same as php strpos.

The closest I have found is:

```
echo $haystack | awk '{print index($0,"<tagtosearch>")}';
```

Tried

```
myvar=$($haystack | awk '{print index($0,"<tagtosearch>")}');
```

but says command not found

The application is to automate include custom bash scripts on a given linux box, but not overwrite existing. Therefore I decided to insert custom start and end tags to denote the custom section. So I simply expected to get the start and end positions, delete this part of the file and pull in a latest version.
So this is as far as I have that function:

```
function install-env(){
   mkdir -p /etc/datadimension/tmp;
   cd /etc/datadimension/tmp;
   cp /etc/bash.bashrc tempbash.bashrc;
   newbash=$(cat tempbash.bashrc);
   echo "$newbash" > newbash.bashrc;
   insertstart=$(echo "$newbash" | awk '{print index($0,"<starttag>")}');
   echo $insertstart;
}
```

Output

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Do I need to apt install something that can handle strings - this seems really basic requirement that is lacking.

Comment: Simply outputing a load of zeros/spaces

Comment: How can we guess without seeing content of `$haystack` and seeing your expected output?

Comment: editted - the expected output would be an integer of the position of <starttag> within the full bash file

Comment: All zeroes mean `<starttag>` is not present in any line. Does it really exist in `/etc/bash.bashrc` anywhere?

Comment: wait - are you saying this is output for each line - I wanted the first matching position within the string, as php does

Comment: by default, a record in awk is a line. You can change the record separator to some character that probably doesn't appear in the file so that the first record is the whole file: (assuning bash) `awk -v RS=$'\x1e' -v needle="<starttag>" '{print index($0, needle)}' <<< "$haystack"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could not find anything acceptable aside from php handling

Answer (score 2):

With `$($haystack)`, you invoke the value assigned to `$haystack` as a command.

To pipe `$haystack` value to `awk` try this:

```
myvar=$(echo "$haystack" | awk '{print index($0,"<tagtosearch>")}');
```

Or as @anubhava suggests in comment, using a [here string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings):

```
myvar=$(awk '{print index($0, "<tagtosearch>")}' <<< "$haystack")
```

Comment: Simply outputing a load of zeros/spaces

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print position of a search word in file then you can use this awk command:

```
awk -v kw='<starttag>' 'p=index($0, kw){p+=b; exit} {b+=length($0)+1} END{print p}' file
```

We keep adding each line's length into a running variable `b` until `index` retuns greater than `0`. At that time we add current line's index into `b` and exit.

Answer (score 0):

This one seems to work like php strpos() function

```
strpos() {
    local string=$1
    local findme=$2

    awk -v x=$string -v y=$findme '{print index($0, y)}' <<< $string
}
```

Some tests

```
strpos azerty a 
1
strpos azerty t
5
strpos azerty er
3
strpos azerty/uio /
7
strpos "azerty uio" " "
7
```

**EDIT:**
If you want exactly the php behaviour you can do:

```
php_strpos() {

    local haystack="$1"
    local needle="$2"
    local offset=${3:-0}

    php -r "echo strpos('$haystack', '$needle', $offset);"
}
```